# Retrieving object from object storage based on metadata

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

retrieving object with metadata using python/boto3

I was able to upload object (files) to object storage via boto3 with metadata inserted into each of the object. Using S3browser i am able to see the metadata correctly attached to the object.

i am trying to write a script to retrieve an object with metadata. i can't find any sample code in the internet with boto3.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide what code you've used so far as that helps us know more about your issue.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about querying or scanning S3 objects using metadata... finding an object based on its metadata, not based on its object key.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes Michael. i wanted to retrieve an object based on unique value of the object's metadata.